# Android application - Internal Testing url not working

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I have an android application published via Managed Play Store. This application is to be published from my organization to other organizations via the "Manage Google Play". However, before publishing the application, I would like this to be tested by some of the users.
I have added their google ids as internal tester and added them in the internal testing track.

However, when I click on the url shared to download the app, it shows a drooling satellite and message "Try again".

Could someone help me understand what I might be doing wrong ?